# Unity2D: I dont want player to die when this exception occurs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My player currently dies when it hits an enemy tagged with "Enemy" and restarts the level using the following script

```
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
   {
     Destroy(gameObject);
     SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
   }
```

I wanted my player to kill the enemy when the bottom of my player hits the enemy, so i created a child gameobject called "Feet" and labelled it "Feet" as well, I also added an edge collider to it. I added the following script to it.

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Now the "Enemy" dies when the "Feet" collides with it, but my player also dies, how do i make an exception to the first script so my player doesnt die when "Feet" collides with the object first instead of the "Player"

Answer (score 1):

You should restrict the collider of the player. It seems like your "Feet" is included in the "Body" of the player. So "Feet" and "Body" touch the Enemy at the same time.

So make the collider of the player smaller at the bottom.

Comment: I made the "Feet" child object of the player, so that they move around together....the "Feet" kills the enemy first, but the player still dies.

Comment: I understand but I think that "Feet" is still inside the "Body" of the player. Can you screen shot your scene tree, espacially "Body" and "Feet" please. Make sure to show us the colliders